# I removed wallpaper, and it seems I've hit a wall. Sand, plaster, or seal?

Tags: concrete, walls, painting, sanding, primer

It seems like pretty rough concrete under there, partly patched with plaster. I'm wondering if the way to go will be to sand it, plaster it, or simply seal with primer. The final goal is white paint, ideally as smooth as possible.

Pretty much all walls in the apartment are like this, with more or less plaster patches, and wallpaper more or less stuck to the wall.

What would you do?

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Comment: Skim coat perhaps?  Still gotta remove all the paper, no matter what.

Comment: `What would you do?` is an opinion based question ... it is off topic here ... please ask about the problem

Comment: More likely plaster patched with drywall compound than concrete patched with plaster.

Answer (score 5):

Using white paint over primer is going to show all kinds of different wall textures due to all the patching and sanding. You'll need a skim coat if you want a really smooth finish. Otherwise, think about getting a slightly textured or deep nap roller and apply a textured finish to the entire wall. One last option would be to install new drywall, seal and paint.

Comment: Note that irregularities can telegraph thru wallpaper, so you'd want to smoothe it even if putting up new paper.